# Uso de un bucle para creación de entries y botones en Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Como la explicación es muy larga, básicamente necesito ayuda para saber en que falla el programa de más abajo. Disculpar la explicación, hace poco que me metí con esto de la programación y todavía confundo conceptos.

Quiero crear un grid con dos filas y cuatro columnas, las tres primeras columnas son entries y la última es para posicionar un botón por fila. Quiero utilizar un bucle for para los entries y otro para los botones, la cosa es que cada entry tiene su propio StringVar, y los dos botones llaman a una misma función con los stringVar de los entries como parámetros, pero son diferentes de un boton a otro. Lo que he hecho ha sido crear un diccionario con listas con las StringsVar que necesito como values. El programa lo que hace es guardar en una variable la info introducida en los entries de la primera columna, la compara con las keys de un diccionario y en caso de que coincidan, carga los valores de estas keys en los demás entries.

Y bueno pues no me funciona :D y no tengo ni idea de porqué, los dos botones funcionan como si tuvieran los mismos parámetros, por lo que hacen lo mismo, copian la info del segundo entry(de la primera columna) pero si lo intento con el primero me da un error.

Pongo un trozo del código:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

d={"luz":{"comp":2,"tlanz":5},"curacion":{"comp":4,"tlanz":8}}

def loadDatas(magic,comp,tlanz):

  magic=magic.get()

  for i in d:
    if magic in d:
      d2=d[magic]


  comp.set(d2["comp"])
  tlanz.set(d2["tlanz"])


hechizos=Frame(root,bg="#3D273D",relief="ridge",bd=3)
hechizos.pack()


inf1=StringVar()
comp1var=StringVar()
tLanz1var=StringVar()

inf2=StringVar()
comp2var=StringVar()
tLanz2var=StringVar()

diccStringVar={
              1:[inf1,comp1var,tLanz1var],
              2:[inf2,comp2var,tLanz2var],
              }



for i in range(len(diccStringVar)):

  dVar=diccStringVar[i+1]
  print(dVar)

  Entry(hechizos,width=15,textvariable=dVar[0]).grid(row=i,column=0,pady=10,padx=10)

  Entry(hechizos,width=2,textvariable=dVar[1]).grid(row=i,column=1,pady=10,padx=10)

  Entry(hechizos,width=4,textvariable=dVar[2]).grid(row=i,column=2,pady=10,padx=10)


for i in range(len(diccStringVar)):

  dVar2=diccStringVar[i+1]

  print(dVar2)

  Button(hechizos,text="L",font=16,bg="#0AD600",command=lambda:loadDatas(dVar2[0],dVar2[1],dVar2[2])).grid(row=i,column=3,padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Muchisimas gracias por adelantado, y cualquier cosa que no se entienda decirme e intento explicarme mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las expresiones `lambda` te están jugando una muy mala pasada. El cuerpo de una función/método o una expresión `lambda` son evaluados cuando son ejecutados, no antes. El intérprete crea el objeto función pertinente y conoce y genera el bytecode para usar las variables locales que se definen en la función en tiempo de definición, lo que no hace es asociar éstas a ningún objeto. La asociación de la variable con el objeto se produce cuando la función se ejecuta, no antes, es lo que se conoce como "late binding".

Tu expresión es:

```
lambda:loadDatas(dVar2[0],dVar2[1],dVar2[2])
```

el problema es que esperas que el valor de `dVar2` en cada iteración quede asociado a la expresión `lambda` generada en esa iteración, pero eso no ocurre. Lo que pasa es que el intérprete cuando evalúa la expresión simplemente tiene en cuenta que **cuando sea ejecutada**, debe buscar una variable global llamada `dVar`, otra `loadDatas` y ejecutar `loadDatas(dVar2[0],dVar2[1],dVar2[2])`, pero insisto, se buscan los valores cuando se ejecuta la `lambda,` no cuando se crea en el ciclo (cuando se define).

El resultado es obvio, cuando pulsas cualquier botón todas las lambdas buscaran el valor de `dVar` en ese momento y en ese momento es el valor que tomó en la última iteración del ciclo (si no la has sobrescrito). Es decir, todas las lambdas pasarán las StringVars de la última key del diccionario.

La solución es usar argumentos por defecto, dado que los argumentos por defecto si siguen un enlazado temprano, se asocian a su valor cuando la función o expresión lambda son definidas, no cuando son ejecutadas:

```
command=lambda dvar=dVar: loadDatas(dvar2[0], dvar2[1], dvar2[2])
```

La otra opción, más eficiente además, es usar `functools.partial`:

```
import functools

command=functools.partial(loadDatas, dvar2[0], dvar2[1], dvar2[2])
```

Aparte de ésto, tu función `loadDatas` tiene un fallo importante, defines `d2=d[magic]` en un condicional, si `magic` no esta en el diccionario, el condicional no se cumple y si no se cumple, no se asigna un valor a la variable `d2`, por lo que `comp.set(d2["comp"])` generará un `UnboundLocalError`.

Para saber si una clave está en un diccionario jamás iteres sobre él, pierdes lo que hace a los diccionarios tan potentes, la eficiencia de las búsquedas en tablas hash. Debes usar el operador de pertenencia `in`:

```
if clave in diccionario:
    valor = diccionario[clave]
```

aunque es aún mejor usar el método `dict.get`:

```
valor = diccionario.get(clave)
if valor is not None:
    # Hacer lo que sea con valor
```

o en Python 3.8:

```
if (valor:= diccionario.get(clave)) is not None:
    # Hacer lo que sea con valor
```

El código, con algunas otras correcciones de estilo quedaría:

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

magics = {
    "luz": {"comp": 2, "tlanz": 5},
    "curacion": {"comp": 4, "tlanz": 8}
    }


def load_data(magic, comp, tlanz):
    magic = magic.get()
    magic_data = magics.get(magic)
    if magic_data is not None:
        comp.set(magic_data["comp"])
        tlanz.set(magic_data["tlanz"])
    else:
        comp.set("")
        tlanz.set("")


hechizos = tk.Frame(root, bg="#3D273D", relief="ridge", bd=3)
hechizos.pack()

inf1 = tk.StringVar(root)
comp1var = tk.StringVar(root)
tlanz1var = tk.StringVar(root)

inf2 = tk.StringVar(root)
comp2var = tk.StringVar(root)
tlanz2var = tk.StringVar(root)

dicc_string_vars={
    1: [inf1, comp1var, tlanz1var],
    2: [inf2, comp2var, tlanz2var]
    }

for i,  (inf,  comp, tlanz) in dicc_string_vars.items():
    tk.Entry(
        hechizos, width=15,textvariable=inf
        ).grid(row= i - 1 , column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

    tk.Entry(
        hechizos, width=2, textvariable=comp
        ).grid(row=i - 1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

    tk.Entry(
        hechizos, width=4, textvariable=tlanz
        ).grid(row=i - 1, column=2, pady=10, padx=10)

for i,  (inf,  comp, tlanz) in dicc_string_vars.items():
    tk.Button(
        hechizos, text="L", font=16, bg="#0AD600",
        command=functools.partial(load_data, inf,  comp,  tlanz)
        ).grid(row=i - 1, column=3, padx=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Ten en cuenta que puedes hacerlo todo en un solo ciclo, incluso generar las StringsVars, por si quieres crear `n` filas sin hardcodear su creación:

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

magics = {
    "luz": {"comp": 2, "tlanz": 5},
    "curacion": {"comp": 4, "tlanz": 8}
    }


def load_data(magic, comp, tlanz):
    magic = magic.get()
    magic_data = magics.get(magic)
    if magic_data is not None:
        comp.set(magic_data["comp"])
        tlanz.set(magic_data["tlanz"])
    else:
        comp.set("")
        tlanz.set("")


hechizos = tk.Frame(root, bg="#3D273D", relief="ridge", bd=3)
hechizos.pack()

rows = 5
dicc_rows = {}

for i in range(1,  rows + 1):
    inf,  comp,  tlanz = (tk.StringVar() for _ in range(3))
    dicc_rows[i] = [inf,  comp,  tlanz]
    tk.Entry(
        hechizos, width=15, textvariable=inf
        ).grid(row= i - 1 , column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

    tk.Entry(
        hechizos, width=2, textvariable=comp
        ).grid(row=i - 1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

    tk.Entry(
        hechizos, width=4, textvariable=tlanz
        ).grid(row=i - 1, column=2, pady=10, padx=10)

    tk.Button(
        hechizos, text="L", font=16, bg="#0AD600",
        command=functools.partial(load_data, inf,  comp,  tlanz)
        ).grid(row=i - 1, column=3, padx=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Madre, esa info me la tengo que estudiar bien, hay cosas que no había visto y me cuesta entenderlas... Se agradece muchisimo tu completísima respuesta, estaba bastante atascado...

Comment: Hola poe, si tienes cualquier duda sobre algo del código de mi respuesta no dudes en comentar e intento explicarlo. Saludos.

Comment: Despues de repasarlo y buscar info, me queda todo más claro, muchas gracias de nuevo no sólo por descubrirme el error sino por la lección

Comment: Buenos días FJSevilla, despues de darle vueltas, sólo hay una cosa que no termino de entender, en el bucle, la linea: "dicc_rows[i] = [inf,  comp,  tlanz]", donde se crea el diccionario con las StringsVars, ¿no se está asignando la misma variable para todos los entries de la misma columna ? Es decir, si se pulsa el boton de la primera fila, no se estaría haciendo .get con todos los entries de la primera columna y .set en los entries de la segunda y tercera columna?

Comment: No, en cada iteración se reasigna un nueva `StringVar` a `inf` otra a `comp` y otra a  `tlanz` (de eso se encarga `inf,  comp,  tlanz = (tk.StringVar() for _ in range(3))`), son tres nuevas StringVars para esa fila, `dicc_rows[i] = [inf, comp, tlanz]` simplemente crea una nueva clave en el diccionario que será `i` (la fila) y le asigna una lista con las tres SringVars para esa fila. En la siguiente iteración se crean otras tres StringVars y una nueva fila en el diccionario con ellas.

Comment: Okey makey, gracias!